# How to move pieces in chess program

Tags: python, chess

as a premice i would like to say that i'm totally new to programming and i'm not a computer science student so i'm sorry if my code makes you cringe, i recently had some python classes and enjoyed them so i wanted to deepen a little so i figured that a simple chess game would be fun to do.

As you can imagine i am using pygame.

As for now i "drew" a chessboard and i blitted the pieces in place, my idea is that i would get the coordinates of every click, if the coordinates are the same (or in range) of the blitted image the variable would update with the second click, how can i make it so that the system recognizes a "first" and "second" click.

```
import pygame as pg
import sys
pg.init()
schermo = pg.display.set_mode((640,540))
def coordinate():
    while True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                mx1, my1 = pg.mouse.get_pos()
                print (mx1,my1)
                return mx1,my1
    pg.display.update()
```

this is how i get the coords

```
ctorrensx = (53,53)
```

[...omissis]

```
def move():
    result = coordinate()
    global ctorrensx
        if result == ctorrensx:
            ctorrensx = (200,200)
```

this was my first idea for the moving function, ctorrensx is an example i wanted to try on, they are the coords of the left black rook, once i would click on it i wanted it to move to the coords (200,200) but it's not happening.

this is my first time using stack overflow so i hope that i didn't create too much confusion on my question.
thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a flag to determine whether the click is a first or second.
For example:

```
firstClick = True

while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if(firstClick):
                    firstClick = False
                    #Code for first click
                else:
                    #code for second click
                    firstClick = True #resets the flag
```